# Using HTTPS in client browsers on a local network without internet connection

Tags: wireless-networking, dns, browser, https, ssl-certificate

I'm working on a web application running on a server. There will be clients (smartphone browsers) connecting to the server via HTTPS over a WiFi that wouldn't be connected to the internet. It would mostly be used for 1-day events.

**The problem:** Is it possible to have HTTPS without the internet?

- We cannot add any certificates to the clients' truststores. Neither can we configure the clients in any other way. Clients will be random people visiting the event
- The clients cannot access the internet to verify CRL/OCSP. There just might be no internet connection

**I have an idea** using a local DNS:

- I own a key and a trusted SSL certificate (LetsEncrypt) for `offline.mydomain.com`
- There is a DNS server in the offline WiFi network that points all DNS addresses to my application server
- All certificates and CRLs from the `offline.mydomain.com` SSL certificate's trust chain are downloaded to the application server and they can be accessed on the paths defined in certificates' CDP and AIA
- The application server claims to be running on `https://offline.mydomain.com` (and the DNS server points `offline.mydomain.com` to the application server)

The whole flow would be:

- **Client:** `GET https://offline.mydomain.com/app`
- **DNS:** `offline.mydomain.com` is on the IP of the application server
- **My application server:** here is the HTML
- ...
- **Client:** `GET http://crl.ca.com/crls/ca.crl`
- **DNS:** `crl.ca.com` is on the IP of the application server
- **My application server:** here is the CRL
- ...
- **Client:** `GET http://certificate.ca.com/certs/ca.cer`
- **DNS:** `certificate.ca.com` is on the IP of the application server
- **My application server:** here is the certificate
- ...

However, I don't understand networking that much.
Would the DNS part be possible?

- Can I make the clients use my local DNS without configuring them manually?
- How much would the clients be confused after connecting back to the real internet?
- Will smartphones connect to a WiFi that is not connected to the internet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think a client would fail to connect to a TLS host just because it couldn't reach the CRL or OCSP server. So I'm 99% sure all you need is:

- A server cert signed by a widely-trusted CA (such as Let's Encrypt), along with the matching private key, installed on your local web server box.
- A local DNS server that points the relevant host name at your local server's IP address.
- A DHCP server to give IP addresses to client devices, and to tell them to use your DNS server.

DNS and DHCP are very lightweight operations, so they can easily run on the same box as the HTTPS server if you want them to.

Mobile Wi-Fi devices will most likely have DHCP enabled, and will most likely be able to use whatever DNS server the DHCP server tells them to use. So I don't think you need to worry about pointing "8.8.8.8"/"8.8.4.4"/"1.1.1.1" at your local DNS server. But I strongly suggest you set up a prototype of your offline network long before the event, and test it out with a variety of iOS, Android, Mac, and Windows devices (at least one of each).

The devices should not be confused at all when connecting back to the real Internet.

Comment: Yes, that's true and it already surprised me before that browsers don't care much about being able to check certificate revocation status. Thanks